# IntelliJ and Maven - Can't create a maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have the newest IntelliJ, and the create Maven project button is gone. I also cant find it in any of the lists.

[See the intellij menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9lRL.png)

You can see the difference here, in IntelliJ's Getting Started with Maven page:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-maven.html

Anyone know how to get it back?

I want it because then you get the structure, and the pom.xml file automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Maven plugin.

Go to Plugins (in IntelliJ; press shift-shift, and search for "plugins"). In Plugins window, search for Maven and install the Maven Plugins.

Comment: Yea! The plugin was turned off for some reason.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but my maven plugin is on. What could be the cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create java project and later right click on your project -> add framework support -> choose maven.